# Talend Open Studio for MDM - connectivity with database

Tags: mysql, talend

I am using Talend Open Studio for MDM and I wish to use MySQL as the MDM Database but it seems that Talend Open Studio for MDM supports only 2 databases - H2 embedded and
eXist XML database.

Is there anyway to load my source data after processing in MDM and directly load it into a MySQL database?

Comment: What reason do you have for needing a non embedded database? If it's because you're deploying into a production environment then you should seriously consider purchasing an enterprise licence. If you are only looking to play with things locally or run on a small server than a H2 database should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

As you've spotted, the Open Studio for MDM edition only properly [supports](https://help.talend.com/display/TalendOpenStudioforMDMInstallationandUpgradeGuide55EN/1.4+Compatible+Databases) an embedded H2 database but also has deprecated support for an eXist database.

The paid for versions that come with enterprise licenses allow for [much more variety](https://help.talend.com/display/TalendPlatformforMDMInstallationandUpgradeGuide55EN/1.6+Compatible+Databases) in back ends and recommends MySQL 5.6+  or Oracle 11+.

Other differences in the versions can be seen [here](https://www.talend.com/products/mdm/matrix).